# MX Linux のログインパスワードが分からなくなった

Tags: linux, debian

VirtualBox上にMX Linux21をインストールし仮想環境を構築しようと思っています。ホストOSはWindows11です。
VirtualBoxとMX Linux21の設定は完了しています。タイムゾーンやキーボード、パソコンの名前やパスワード、root管理者用のパスワード等設定が完了し、再起動をしました。

お恥ずかしい話なのですが、そこへパスワードを打ち込んだのですがエラーが出ました。
ちゃんと最初のパスワードと確認用のパスワードを設定しています。
急いでいたので入力をミスしたようです。少し前に試したときははroot管理者用のパスワードは設定していなかった気がします。

[image: パスワードエラー]

何回か再起動したり探してサイトに載っていたやり方を試したりしてみたのですがうまくいきません。

現状、再起動しようが試しにキーボードを打ったりしてみたのですが添付画像から進めません。

こういう場合、削除して再度インストールする必要がありますか？

仮想環境やLinuxに関しては全くの初心者です。動画サイトを見ながら設定をしました。

このような状態からパスワード再設定する方法などわかる方いらっしゃいましたら教えて下さい。　
また以下の画面より設定がおかしいようでしたらご指摘願います。

あとキーボードでレイアウトは日本語を選択してあるのですが、キーボードモデルは選択肢があまりにも多く、自分の使っているキーボードのモデルも検索してはみたのですが結局わかりませんでした。そこでとりあえずMicrosoft オフィスを選択して先に進みました。後から設定変更可能なのでしょうか？またここは何を選択したら良いのでしょうか？

併せてよろしくお願いいたします。

[image: プレビュー画面]

Comment: インストール時に「一般ユーザー」と「rootユーザー」のパスワードを設定しているはずなので、まずはそれらをよく確認してみてください (基本的には一般ユーザーでログインすべきです)。

Comment: https://linuxfan.info/post-3161 によると、起動時にSHIFTキーを押し続けることでGRUBメニューが表示されるようです。そのときの画面でリカバリーモードが選択できませんか？

Comment: Q&A・調査・試行錯誤に時間を使うよりも、それは削除して新しい環境を構築した方が早いと思われますが、削除等も出来ない状態なのでしょうか？